# force Download a file from AWS s3 rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to know if someone know a way to force download a file from AWS. For some security reason I've transfer some files from my google drive to s3. For the google docs there is an url that permit to download the file with his id. Maybe there is a similar process for s3?
I'd like that the users of my rails app can download the file on a simple link.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "force" a download?

Comment: I don't know how to say it differently, i want that when you click on the link it automaticly download the file.

Comment: So when they currently click a link, it doesn't download the file? What does it do instead?

Comment: I was using googleDoc for do it but now I don't know how to create this link using a s3 storage

Comment: So the question is literally "How do I create a link to a file in S3" instead of some vague notion of "forcing" a download? Now that I've helped you understand the question you are trying to ask please try to search for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologies for my really bad english. When I said "force download link" it's a link that permit to the users to automaticly download the file stored in s3 from my rails app.

I've found a way to do this. to access to a aws file the link is :

href="http://bucket-name.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/filename.wtf"

To permit to the user to download it you have to change the permission of you're bucket to everyone. And add this following code to the bucket edit policy :

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
]
}
```

Don't forget to change the bucketname with you're

Then you have to change and add metadata of you're file inside you're bucket with:

content-Type -> application/force-download

content-Disposition -> attachment;filename="filename.wtf"

Just change the "filename.wtf" with you're

Hope that help!